# Transform a Select into NativeSelect with MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, material-ui

There is a Select and I want to change it to NativeSelect, the problem is that it doesn't do anything when it's clicked.

The dropdown doesn't show the values. I've read that on NativeSelect the value is casted to string. The values in my dropdown are already string.

How can this be solved?

The following is my code working. If **Select** is replaced by **NativeSelect** it doesn't work anymore.

```
<FormControl className='searchBrand'>
  <InputLabel id='brandLabel'>Brand</InputLabel>
  <Select
    labelId='brandLabel'
    id='brandLabel'
    renderValue={this.getSelectedBrandFilter}
    value={this.props.brandFilter}
    onChange={this.handleChangeBrand}
    multiple
  >
    {this.props.platformFilter.length > 0
      ? brands.map((brand) => (
          <MenuItem key={brand} value={brand}>
            <div>{brand}</div>
          </MenuItem>
        ))
      : ''}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Comment: For `NativeSelect` (you can also just specify the `native` prop on `Select`), you need to use `<option>` elements as the children instead of `<MenuItem>` elements.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I changed like you said: https://pastebin.com/grReSc5A but now it is not working and it shows instead of the dropdown like this: https://imgur.com/S3NPw5C

Comment: I'm putting the whole file, maybe it's easier to understand the problem: https://pastebin.com/rAGty49E

Comment: You can’t put divs and images in options for a native select. It only supports what is valid in an html select element.

Comment: is there a way to use something else that supports images?

Comment: That’s the whole purpose of the `Select` component (without the `native` prop).

Comment: the main reason I wanted to use NativeSelect is becasue I don't like how it behaves when I click on a Select. So I've found in NativeSelect (https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#native-select) the third example from that list which doesn't make the initial text smaller and throws it up. I just wanted a normal, simple select. But I don't know if it's possible with Select

Comment: The text that shrinks and moves up is the label. You can leave out the `InputLabel` element if you want to. A lot of customization is possible with `Select`. If there are aspects of the look that you want to change and aren't sure how, I recommend creating a new question for the specific aspect you want to change.